# laravel Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequest does not exist

Tags: forms, laravel, validation

when i submit a form and run form validation then it gaves me this error but my form validation is working on other page 
In that file **\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php**

```
/**
 * Handle dynamic calls to class methods.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \BadMethodCallException
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    $rule = Str::snake(substr($method, 8));

    if (isset($this->extensions[$rule])) {
        return $this->callExtension($rule, $parameters);
    }

    throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
        'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
    ));
}
```

**Errror=** Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequest does not exist

Comment: Can you show us the code that raises the error?

Comment: Well i found the error it is in my validation rules

Answer (score 26):

You wrote **request** instead of **required** here:

```
$data = $request->validate([
    'field' => 'request|string|max:255',
]);
```

Trying to fire **validateRequest** method suggest you were trying to use 'request' validation rule which doesn't exist.

All valid rules you can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#available-validation-rules), but I think you just made a typo.

Comment: I had the same error too. Inaccurate spelling was the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Validator facade class

**In you Controller**

```
use Validator;
```

See link [Laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators)